# Uninitialized Constant on custom Puppet Function

Tags: puppet

I've got a function that I'm trying to run on my puppetmaster on each client run.  It runs just fine on the puppetmaster itself, but it causes the agent runs to fail on the nodes because of the following error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: uninitialized constant Puppet::Parser::Functions::<my_module>
```

I'm not really sure why.  I enabled debug logging on the master via config.ru, but I see the same error in the logs with no more useful messages.

What other steps can I take to debug this?

**Update:**
Adding some extra details.

Puppet Community, with Foreman connected Puppetmaster running on Apache2 with Passenger / Rack

Both client and master are running Puppet 3.7.5

Both client and master are Ubuntu 14.04

Both client and master are using Ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]

Pluginsync is enabled

The custom function works fine on the puppetmaster when run run as part of the puppetmaster's manifest (it's a client of itself) or using puppet apply directly on the server.

The function is present on the clients, and when I update for debugging purposes I do see the file appear on the client side.

I cannot paste the function here unfortunately because it is proprietary code. It does rely on the aws-sdk, but I have verified that that ruby gem is present on both the client and the master side, with the same version in both places.  I've even tried surrounding the entire function with:

```
begin
rescue LoadError
end
```

and have the same result.

Comment: Check if your custom function file is present on the clients or not

Comment: strange. functions should only run on the master anyway. Custom functions do not run on agent nodes.

Comment: also. try enabling pluginsync https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html#pluginsync

Comment: @ptierno no you're right, it is of no consequence whether the function is synced to the agent or not. The reported error happens during compilation, master side. OP: This is lacking information. In which file is the function defined? How is it invoked? How exactly is it working "on the puppetmaster itself"? Please also add the complete function definition to the question.

Comment: @FelixFrank - I updated with some more details.

Comment: @DanR - I'm still confused on what your are trying to do. In a master/node environment, custom functions only execute on the MASTER, not on an agent node. Using puppet apply with the function successfully is probably due to pluginsync being enabled. puppet apply would be the only use case i can think of where a function is executed on an agent node.

Comment: We don't need the body of the function, but it is necessary to see 1) the path to the rb file 2) the boilerplate parts of the function and 3) its invocation from the manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is embarrassingly stupid, but it turns out I had somehow never noticed that I hadn't actually included this line in my function:

```
require 'aws-sdk'
```

And so the error I was receiving:

```
uninitialized constant Puppet::Parser::Functions::Aws
```

Was actually referring to the AWS SDK being missing, and not a problem with the puppet module itself (which was also confusingly named aws), which is how I was interpreting it.  Basically, I banged my head against the wall for several days over a painfully silly mistake.  Apologies to all who tried to help me :)